# Limitations associated with returning a reference as opposed to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What is the difference between returning by pointer and returning by reference? In both cases, the address is returned to the caller, am I right?

According to this little program - its obviously the same - it prints the value of an integer.

Are the any limitations concerning returning by reference rather than returning by pointer?
My teacher tells us - when you return by reference to a receiver, the receiver "borrows" the object. When you on the other hand return a pointer - you "transfer" the ownership of the object to the receiver.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int x;

  public:
    A() : x(10) { }

    void print() {
        cout << "x = : " << x << endl;
    }

};

class B {
    int y;

  public:
    B() : y(30) { }

    void print() {
        cout << "x = : " << y << endl;
    }

    A& create() {
        A* a = new A;
        return *a;
    }
};
```

Return by pointer, then these parts of the code I changed:

```
A* create() {
   A* a = new A;
   return a;
}
```

And in the main:

```
 b.create()->print();
```

Comment: Your reference example is a memory leak, caller can't free that allocation.

Comment: what if you return nullptr?

Answer (score 3):

When you return a reference, you make an alias way to access to the object. It's like you are accessing the object directly.

By returning a pointer, you **copy** (not transfer) the address of the object. Then you need deferenece the pointer to access the object.

I think you can take a look at smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to understand transfering the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

References are always treated as alias to original object, so no separate memory allocated to reference. Where as pointer has a separate memory address and store address of object.

Comment: "no separate memory allocated" - references are implemented using pointers by many popular compilers. So this is not really true. But you're right semantically: I can never take the address of a reference, whereas I can take a pointer's address.